# Serialize Case Class to Json in Play Framework with Timestamp

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework

I'm trying to serialize an object to Json using the play framework, but one of the parameters of the object is a Timestamp object. Therefore when I call

```
implicit val eventFormat = Json.format[Event]
```

I get an error that Timestamp is not serialized. I know that I could manually write out the Writes function wherein I do each member individually and in turn convert the Timestamp object to a DateTime object, but I was wondering if there were an easier way.

I'm ultimately trying to serialize a case class which is a map, mapping a string to an Event and therefore need to serialize the Event as painlessly as possible.

Comment: You could provides `Format[Timestamp]` so that the `format` macro can generate `OFormat` for case classes having `Timestamp` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```scala
import java.sql.Timestamp
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import play.api.libs.json._

    object Event {
      implicit val timestampFormat = new Format[Timestamp] {
        def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Timestamp] = json match{
          case JsNumber(bigDecimal) =>
            JsSuccess(new Timestamp(bigDecimal.toLong))
          case JsString(txtFormat) =>
            JsSuccess(new Timestamp(DateTime.parse(txtFormat).getMillis))
          case _ =>
            JsError(s"Wrong timestamp format: $json")
        }
        def writes(o: Timestamp): JsValue = JsNumber(o.getTime)
        //def writes(o: Timestamp): JsValue = JsString(new DateTime(o.getTime).toString)
      }
      implicit val eventFormat = Json.format[Event]
    }

    case class Event(timestamp:Timestamp)
```